# ffmpeg C API - creating queue of frames

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg

I have created using the C API of ffmpeg a C++ application that reads frames from a file and writes them to a new file. Everything works fine, as long as I write immediately the frames to the output. In other words, the following structure of the program outputs the correct result (I put only the pseudocode for now, if needed I can also post some real snippets but the classes that I have created for handling the ffmpeg functionalities are quite large):

```
AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
int got_frame;

// readFrame returns 0 if file is ended, got frame = 1 if
// a complete frame has been extracted
while(readFrame(inputfile,frame, &got_frame)) {
  if (got_frame) {
    // I actually do some processing here
    writeFrame(outputfile,frame);
  }
}
av_frame_free(&frame);
```

The next step has been to parallelize the application and, as a consequence, frames are not written immediately after they are read (I do not want to go into the details of the parallelization). In this case problems arise: there is some flickering in the output, as if some frames get repeated randomly. However, the number of frames and the duration of the output video remains correct.

What I am trying to do now is to separate completely the reading from writing in the serial implementation in order to understand what is going on. I am creating a queue of pointers to frames:

```
std::queue<AVFrame*> queue;
int ret = 1, got_frame;
while (ret) {
  AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
  ret = readFrame(inputfile,frame,&got_frame);
  if (got_frame) 
    queue.push(frame);
}
```

To write frames to the output file I do:

```
while (!queue.empty()) {
  frame = queue.front();
  queue.pop();
  writeFrame(outputFile,frame);
  av_frame_free(&frame);
}
```

The result in this case **is an output video with the correct duration and number of frames that is only a repetition of the last 3 (I think) frames of the video.**

My guess is that something might go wrong because of the fact that in the first case I use always the same memory location for reading frames, while in the second case I allocate many different frames.

Any suggestions on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, so I'm assuming that `readFrame()` is a wrapper around libavformat's `av_read_frame()` and libavcodec's `avcodec_decode_video2()`, is that right?

From the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__decoding.html#ga3ac51525b7ad8bca4ced9f3446e96532):

> When `AVCodecContext.refcounted_frames` is set to 1, the frame is
>   reference counted and the returned reference belongs to the caller.
>   The caller must release the frame using `av_frame_unref()` when the
>   frame is no longer needed.

and:

> When
>   `AVCodecContext.refcounted_frames` is set to 0, the returned reference
>   belongs to the decoder and is valid only until the next call to this
>   function or until closing or flushing the decoder.

Obviously, from this it follows from this that you need to set `AVCodecContext.refcounted_frames` to 1. The default is 0, so my gut feeling is you need to set it to 1 and that will fix your problem. Don't forget to use `av_fame_unref()` on the pictures after use to prevent memleaks, and also don't forget to free your `AVFrame` in this loop if `got_frame = 0` - again to prevent memleaks:

> ```
> while (ret) {
>   AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
>   ret = readFrame(inputfile,frame,&got_frame);
>   if (got_frame) 
>     queue.push(frame);
>   else
>     av_frame_free(frame);
> }
> ```

(Or alternatively you could implement some cache for `frame` so you only realloc it if the previous object was pushed in the queue.)

Comment: THANK YOU! This was exactly my problem!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing obviously wrong with your pseudocode.  The problem almost certainly lies in how you lock the queue between threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to specify that I put aside for the moment the parallelization and that the queue is built sequentially (I edited my question),

Comment: If you don't want to post the full code, I suggest logging the pushed and popped frame pointer addresses.  Make sure you're seeing the same sequence of addresses in both directions.

Comment: You can also log the frame's pts and verify its monotonicity.

Answer (score 0):

Your memory allocation seems same to me. Do you maybe do something else in between reading and writing the frames?

Is `queue` the same queue in the routines that read and write the frames?